# Algorithm for checking hour periods

Tags: algorithms

I have the following array that contains a day and the scheduled hours, i wanna know how to check if the given time falls in a period of that array, for example let's say the current time is 20:50 how to know if it's in that scheduled array?

```
{
   "monday":[
      "00:00", // Period number 1
      "00:15",
      "00:30",
      "00:45",
      "01:00",
      "01:15",
      "01:30",
      "01:45",
      "02:00",
      "02:15",
      "02:30",
      "02:45",
      "03:00",
      "03:15",
      "03:30",
      "03:45",
      "04:00",
      "04:15",
      "04:30",
      "04:45",
      "05:00",
      "05:15",
      "05:30",
      "05:45",
      "06:00",
      "06:15",
      "06:30",
      "12:30", // Period number 2
      "12:45",
      "13:00",
      "13:15",
      "13:30",
      "13:45",
      "14:00",
      "19:30", // Period number 3
      "19:45",
      "20:00",
      "20:15",
      "20:30",
      "20:45",
      "21:00",
      "21:15",
      "21:30",
      "21:45",
      "22:00",
      "22:15",
      "22:30",
      "22:45",
      "23:00",
      "23:15",
      "23:30",
      "23:45"
   ],
}
```

Comment: You just want to check if the entry exists in the array or you also want to know in which period it falls?

Comment: @Inuyashayagami I want to know in which period it falls

Comment: Please don't add clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your question to incorporate that information into the question and make sure it will be clear for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @D.W. is suggesting, you can use the binary search technique which takes $O(\log n)$ time, where $n$ is the number of elements in the list.

Furthermore, if you want to know the corresponding period, there are many ways to it.
For example, You can make a separate array of periods and then perform a binary search on it.

---

Furthermore, you can improve the query time to $O(1)$ by maintaining an array of size 1440 = 24x60 as follows:

The $i^{th}$ entry of the array corresponds to the time $a:b$ where $a = i /60$ and $b = i \mod 60$. And, the value at $i^{th}$ entry is $1$ if time $a:b$ is in the list else it is $0$. Therefore, you can check in $O(1)$ time if an entry exist in the array.

To know the period in $O(1)$ time, you can maintain additional information in the array about the period in which the time lies. For example: an $i^{th}$ entry lies in $2^{nd}$ period. So basically it would be a two-dimensional array.

Comment: This is perfect Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).  This will find whether the time is in the list, and if it is not, the entry immediately before and after that time.

Comment: I want to know the period it's in and not look for it in the list

Comment: @0x58, this *does* tell you the period it is in: as I said in the answer, it finds "the entry immediately before and after that time".